# How to make empty Pandas DataFrame with named columns and then add a row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Questions:**

1. How to make empty `Pandas DataFrame`, name 2 columns in it?
2. How to add a row for previously created DataFrame?

Can somebody help please? My code below doesn't work properly, it returns strange DataFrame.

**My code:**

```
data_set = pd.DataFrame(columns=['POST_TEXT', 'TARGET'])

data_set[data_set.shape[0]] = ['Today is a great day!', '1']
```

**Code result:**

[image]

Comment: you need to use loc to assign a row `data_set.loc[data_set.shape[0]] = ['Today is a great day!', '1']`, otherwise it is a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data_set = pd.DataFrame(columns=['POST_TEXT', 'TARGET'])

# output
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [POST_TEXT, TARGET]
Index: []

# add row
data_set = data_set.append({"POST_TEXT": 5, "TARGET": 10}, ignore_index=True)

# output
  POST_TEXT TARGET
0         5     10
```

So to append row you have to define `dict` where key is name of the column and value is the value you want to append.

If you would like to add row and populate only one column:

```
data_set = data_set.append({"POST_TEXT": 50}, ignore_index=True)

# output
   POST_TEXT  TARGET
0       50.0     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of adding the value post-creation, it is possible to add it during creation:

```
data_set = pd.DataFrame(columns=['POST_TEXT', 'TARGET'], data=[['Today is a great day!', '1']])
```